# How is the "base" score calculated, for the online game?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, scoring

In the online Ticket to Ride game, after the last cards are played, a "base" score is shown for each player.

[image]
How is this score calculated?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Just the same as in the tabletop version, these are the points gained for claiming routes - i.e. `1/2/4/7/10/15` points for a route of length `1/2/3/4/5/6` (in the original game, slight variation in different versions). It's where your scoring marker would be in the tabletop game.

Comment: I've never played the tabletop version. 
In the online game, immediately after the last card is played, each team is shown as having "base" points. This is before the animated pictures of the trains move forward to show how much each team scored for each route. 
Do you mean that these "base" points are calculated just from the lengths of the routes in the tickets that one took, whether or not one was successful in completing the routes?

Comment: No, they are from the routes you claim; assuming you're playing the Days of Wonder implementation (the official one), you can see the points adding up as you play through the game. Your tickets (other than the number you have taken) are hidden information until game end.